# jQuery Tab Menu with Remember Last Position

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have `jQuery` tab menu call ajax.

Menu is working perfect, now How can I set the tab automatically detect last tab click even page refreshed.

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/rw8ujfg3/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up " id="friends">
  <li active><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
```

```
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;
});
```

I just know it will be using cookie right? But how can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Use document.cookie="your format" to store data in cookie, then check it accordingly

I think it may got a better answer, but that's all i can do

Hope i can help you, Here you go

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("opentab=") >= 0) {
var x = document.cookie;
if(x=='opentab=1st'){
  var dataid = '#contacts_tab';
}
else if(x=='opentab=2nd'){
  var dataid = '#friends_list_tab';
}
else{
  var dataid = '#awaiting_request_tab';
}
var loadurl = $(dataid).attr('href');
var targ = $(dataid).attr('data-target');
$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$(dataid).tab('show');
}

$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    if(id == "contacts_tab"){
    document.cookie = "opentab=1st";
}
else if(id == "friends_list_tab"){
    document.cookie = "opentab=2nd";
}
else{
    document.cookie = "opentab=3rd";
}

$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;
});
```